# How to set up the Back button in the ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar-compat

I have this issue in my code, I can't setup the back button in the ActionBar.
I specified in the AndroidManifest that AProposActivity is a child activity to MainActivity but I have `java.lang.NullPointerException.`
There is my code java :

```
 public class AProposActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apropos);

    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
}
```

and my xml file :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.emi.integre.projet.dentistterms.AProposActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/apropos1"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/apropos2"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/name1"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/name2"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/name3"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/name4"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/apropos4"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/apropos3"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/name5"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8" />
```

there is also my AndroidManifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.emi.integre.projet.dentistterms">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AcceuilActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultActivity"
        android:label="Voici le terme dans les 3 langues"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.emi.integre.projet.dentistterms.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="Rechercher un terme"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.emi.integre.projet.dentistterms.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AProposActivity" android:label="A Propos"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.emi.integre.projet.dentistterms.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>

</application>
```

here is also my styles.xml file :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navigationBarColor
    </item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/drawerArrowColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` for your Application in the AndroidManifest.xml, the `ActionBar` will not be inflated. You could either use the [ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html), declaring it in your layout and calling

```
 setSupportActionBar((ToolBar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar));
```

before any `getSupportActionBar()` call, or change the `theme` with one that has the `ActionBar` support

Comment: Wich Themes have ActionBar support ?

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light` for instance.

Comment: I changed the theme but the problem remains

Comment: where did you change it ? in the activity's tag? in the application's tag? in styles.xml?

Comment: what's the parent of @style/AppTheme?

Comment: I believe that the problem is my styles.xml file : <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: that's not AppTheme. Edit your question. Add the whole file.

Comment: delete `android:theme=` from you all `<activity` tags in the Manifest and leave it only in the `<application` tag. Clean the prject and run it again

Comment: what does *not working* mean ? Does the app crash? Would you mind sharing more information ?

Comment: In calling the activity AProposActivity the app crash

Comment: NullPointerException : attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled' on a null object reference

Comment: Remove `item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` from AppTheme

Comment: Remove those attributes from AppTheme in styles.xml

Comment: i have this problem :java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Make a `xml` which having `toolbar` name it `toolbar_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Step 2:** You have to add the above toolbar in your activity layout which you can do it by including it as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

 <include
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3:** Make changes in your `onCreate()` method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apropos);

    ToolBar toolbar = (ToolBar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //your code here
}
```

**Step 4:** In `onOptionsItemSelected()` check the id as follows:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            //onBackPressed();  //you can call this directly 
                      //OR
            //your code implementation if any 
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: I have this issue for your code : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference

Comment: `Toolbar.getTitle()`  i am not doing that in my code

Comment: Me also ! The problem remains

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default ActionBar then use,

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) method add following line of code

```
case android.R.id.Home :
       this.finish();
       return true;
```

Comment: Import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar instead of android.app.ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void enableActionBarHomeButton(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity){
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Then make a function call as follow

```
enableActionBarHomeButton(this);
```